# Put Sequence ID from specific date

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number

I'm trying to put sequence id which should start from current date then backwards and should only limit up until 5 rows. I can't do by date as there are times there are missing date row so I still have to follow the current date to whatever date is next backwards

I already came up with a query but it seems that it doesn't really start with current date backwards. Any other approach I can do?

```
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by employee_id order by date rows 5 preceding exclude current row)
from employee table
```

[image]

Comment: please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need to list employee columns such as employee id(you did `select *`). If so, you need something like this:

```
select main.* from (select distinct emp from test ) t1,
  lateral(select emp, dt, row_number() over (partition by emp order by dt desc) rn
  from test t2 where t1.emp = t2.emp
  and t2.dt <= now()
  group by t2.emp, t2.dt
  order by t2.dt desc
  limit 5) main
  order by 1, 2 desc;
```

Inside of the lateral join you get last 5 date for each group and then iterate it.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7FwkleKY)

Also, there is a different version of it:

```
with main as (select emp, dt from test
group by emp, dt
  having dt <= now()), final as(
  select emp, dt, row_number() over (partition by emp order by dt desc) rn
  from main where dt <= now())
  select * from final where rn <= 5;
```

In order to compare them I increased the data volume and you can see comparison of explain output for both queries using [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p1IlCZL7?hide=4).

In short, second query is faster.

Note: there were mistakes on the answer, they were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

Example with sample data:

Temp Table:

```
create temp table temp_emp 
( 
    employee_id int,
    date date
);
```

Sample data:

```
insert into temp_emp values(1,'2023-08-02');
insert into temp_emp values(2,'2023-08-01');
insert into temp_emp values(3,null);
insert into temp_emp values(4,'2023-07-31');
insert into temp_emp values(5,'2023-07-29');
insert into temp_emp values(6,null);
insert into temp_emp values(7,'2023-08-03');
insert into temp_emp values(8,'2023-07-03');
insert into temp_emp values(9,'2023-01-01');
insert into temp_emp values(10,null);
```

Query:

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by (case when date <=  now() then 1 else null end) order by date desc) rnk
    from temp_emp
)
select date, case when rnk <= 5 and date <=now() then rnk else null end as ranks
from cte;
```

Result:

[image]